# Function SvyCreateTableOne can't work for a continuous variable

Tags: r, printing, summary

I noticed a problem when I run the `svycreatetableone` function. This error message occurs :

```
Error in round(n, digits = digits) : argument non numérique pour une fonction mathématique.
```

I get continuous and categorical variable in the function.

An other contributor had the same problem : [why function svyCreateTableOne works but i can´t print continuous results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578983/why-function-svycreatetableone-works-but-i-can%c2%b4t-print-continuous-results)

He fixed the problem using Rtools.
Knowing that I have the latest versions of Rtools and devtools, how to solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us how you used the `svycreatetableone` function to create this error, or make a simple example for others to run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.